# Cannot convert 'int*' to 'float*' for argument '1'

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

I am copying and integer array into float array using pointers

```
// Copy This code into main.cpp file

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int array1[5];

    int array2[7];

    float array3[5];

    int x;

    cout << "Enter 5 values :" << endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            cin >> array1[i];
        }

        cout << "Enter 7 values :" << endl;
        for ( int j = 0; j < 7; j++ )
        {
            cin >> array2[j];
        }

    cout << "Please choose an option from the list : " << endl
     << "\t 1. integer array copy " << endl
     << "\t 2. float array copy " << endl
     << "\t 3. delete single row of array " << endl
     << "\t 4. delete block of  rows into array " << endl
     << "\t 5. add a row into the array " << endl
     << "\t 6. add block of rows into array " << endl
     << "\t 7. Quit " << endl;

    cin >> x;

    if ( x == 1 )

    {

        int *z = arrayCopy ( array1, 5, array2, 7 );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

            cout << z[i] << " ";

         }

        cout << endl ;

    }

    else if ( x == 2 )

    {

        float *z = floatArrayCopy ( array1, 5, array2, 7 );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

            cout << z[i] << " ";

         }

        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;

}


// And copy this code into "arrayUtil.h" file

int *arrayCopy( int *a, int size1, int *b, int size2)

{

    int *c = new int[size1 + size2];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size1; i++)

    {

        c[i] = a[i];

    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size2; i++)

    {
        c[size1 + i] = b[i];
    }

    return c;
}

float *floatArrayCopy( float *a, int size1, float *b, int size2)

{

    float *c = new float[size1 + size2];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size1; i++)

    {

        c[i] = a[i];

    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size2; i++)

    {
        c[size1 + i] = b[i];

    }

    return c;

}
```

It is giving error.. I changed the parameter values as well as pointer types but still giving problem.. Need to know WHY???

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: In `floatArrayCopy ( array1, 5, array2, 7 )`, you are passing an array of `int`s to a function expecting an array of `float`s. The error message seems perfectly clear.

Comment: I changed the type and it still gives the error

Comment: While you often can implicitly convert an `int` value to a `float` value, and the other way around, an array of `int` values is very different from an array of `float` values.

Comment: yeah but what can I do here.. I thought it will be okay after changing the argument types.. int values will simply be copies into float but it is giving error.

Comment: Also, when creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), make sure it actually builds without any errors or warnings unrelated to the problem you're asking about. The code you show will *not* build cleanly like that, the error you're asking about will not be the only one, and you will probably have warnings as well.

Comment: ***I changed the type and it still gives the error*** I don't think you changed it to: `float *floatArrayCopy( int *a, int size1, int* b, int size2)` although that seems like it would be named wrongly in that case.

Comment: well i did this:
float *floatArrayCopy( float *a, float size1, float *b, float size2)

and it still gives error:
error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'float* floatArrayCopy(float*, float, float*, float)'
   float *z = floatArrayCopy ( array1, 5, array2, 7 );

Comment: Your change does not make much sense. You don't have 2 float arrays as parameters. And you would not want to return just a single float. And you don't want a float as the size.

Comment: you are right.. But the problem is that, arrays passed in arguments are integer but it is not changing as float when it is being used into floatArrayCopy function.. How can I change it to flaot ??

Comment: You don't want to do that. You want to pass the int arrays as I said above and return a float array. Not pass float arrays. Again rename the function so it makes sense.

Comment: It worked man.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of the call

> ```
> float *z = floatArrayCopy ( array1, 5, array2, 7 );
> ```

in which `array1` and `array2` are arrays of `int` (so would be converted to pointers to `int` - i.e. `int *`) versus the function definition

> ```
> float *floatArrayCopy( float *a, int size1, float *b, int size2);
> ```

When passing pointers, it is necessary for the pointer types to match - a `float *` and an `int *` do not match.

A C++ compiler would have diagnosed this, and given an error message reflecting the above.

The solution in your case is to pass arrays of `float` to the function, not arrays of `int`.

Comment: I know a way to store every value from int array to float using a for loop, but I don't know how to do it dynamically using pointers.. Your answer is really satisfying.. Now how can I pass int array as float to  the "floatArrayFunction" in arguments????

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan just do what I said and it will work. Although I would change its name: something like this `float* copyAndConvertIntArraysToFloatArray(int* ar1, int size1, int* ar2, int size2);`

Comment: @drescherjm it worked.. Thanks a lot.. <3 (y)